# How to use spark Vector.foreachActive method?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In doc:

```
org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
@Since("2.0.0")
def foreachActive(f: (Int, Double) => Unit): Unit
```

My code is:

```
var map: Map[Int,Double] = Map()
vectors.first().foreachActive((a,b) => map += (a -> b))
println(map.max)

var maxValue: Map[Int,Double] = Map()
var maps: Map[Int,Double] = Map()
vectors.map(vec => {
  vec.foreachActive((a,b) => maps += (a -> b))
  maxValue += maps.max
})
println(maxValue)
```

Result in console is:

```
(257376,1.2809338454620642)
Map()
```

Why I can't get maxValue?

Comment: In the first case you are using action - "first()" in the second case you justdefine map function withou action. Execution is lazy and u can try to use eg. Collect

Comment: Thank you! It works when I use  vectors.collect().map.